# Stuck with evenly resizing an image animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate this effect:

http://www.eginstill.com/

I tired everything, I got it to resize but can't get that effect where image is fixed and its being resized from all sides.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    </head>
    
    <style>
    body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    
    
    
    <div id="menu" style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 1000px; background: black; display: inline-block;">
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="img-01" style="z-index: 100; width: 100%; position: absolute;">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/95/c3/70/95c3708a97e9a7e56d4e13166dd5dd24.jpg" id="photograph" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
    
    
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#img-01").click(function () {
                    $("#img-01").animate({
                     height: '400px',
                        width: '400px',
                        left: '300px'
    
                    }, 1500);
                });
            });
    
    </script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    
        $('#photograph').hide();
        $('#photograph').each(function(i) {
            if (this.complete) {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $(this).load(function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Not sure what to do. Thanks.

Comment: If you check the site source code, you'll see that they use 4 divs to hide the top, bottom, left, and right and they change image size. It don't answer you question, but I hope I would help you

Comment: Okay, can you help me break it down? Understand how they did it? I'm new at this and unaware.

I would love to receive on how to do it.

Comment: I think it's quite a "complicated code" because they have to move many elements.. I don't really know how they do that, I just can advise you to use JQuery to simplify the css updates and animations

Comment: Okay Okay thanks. So your saying their approach is different.

Im doing it wrong then. Instead I should be moving 4 separate boxes and scaling down the image?

Comment: If I had to do this, I'll wrap the picture on a div with `position:absolute and top,bottom,letf,right = 0 and overflow:hidden`. Inside, a img with `position:fixed`. And when you'll want to move like your example, only change the div's top|bottom|left|right properties

Comment: Yeah, tried. Only works for bottom movement.. rest doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

Please see the snippet in this code.

- I changed your IDs by class (it's more convenient, we prefer use class instead of ids.)
- updated the css of .img-01 element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img-01").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      top: '20px',
      right: '100px',
      left: '30px',
      bottom: '20px'
    }, 1500);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.photograph').hide();
  $('.photograph').each(function(i) {
    if (this.complete) {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(this).load(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-01 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/95/c3/70/95c3708a97e9a7e56d4e13166dd5dd24.jpg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="menu"></div>

  <div class="img-01">
    </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think what the issue is.. the image must be in the middle? Cause in the example the image is steady.. just the parent is shrinking in.. my code the image is scaling in it seems not steady like in the example...

Comment: Okay just saw it, it works! THANK YOUUUUUU!!!! So it was the background-attachment fixed.. OKAYYYY THANK YOUUU

Comment: Haha, you're welcome ! Glad to help you :)
Background-attachment fixed is used to create a parallax-style, even if you scroll the background image won't move. In fact, in that case, the div is the viewport of the picture !

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer if it's the solution you wanted :)